# Codeigniter 4 - multiple applications

Tags: codeigniter, web-applications

With Codeigniter version 3 - you could run multiple applications under one installation. With Codeigniter 4 I can't seem to get it working per instructions: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html

My server is configured using wamp as follows:

C:/wamp/www

/system

/frontend
app/
public
writable

/backend
app/
public
writable

c:/wamp/www/frontend/public/index.php -> configured as follows:

```
$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . '../frontend/app/Config/Paths.php');
```

c:/wamp/www/frontend/app/config/paths.php -> configured as follows:

```
public $systemDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../../system';
public $appDirectory = __DIR__ . 'frontend/app';
```

I'm not sure if these folders are pointing properly...Any ideas would help.

Thanks,
Jeremiah

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue through trial and error. ../ goes up one level in directories each time (as I had assumed).

In the Paths.php file I had to removed the default value ***DIR*** sample below:

Before:

```
public $appDirectory = __DIR__ . '/..';
```

After:

```
public $appDirectory = '../../frontend/app';
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me following the [CI4 documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html).

I created two folders for my two apps, each with copies of `/app`, `/public` and `/writable`.  I do not have `/tests`:

```
system/
frontend/   
  /app   
  /public
  /writable
backend/
  /app    
  /public
  /writable
```

Then I had to change `systemDirectory` in Paths.php from:

```
public $systemDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../../system';
```

to:

```
public $systemDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../../../system';
```